# functions in useState are erring as not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use react hooks but I must be missing something. I'm getting not a function for any of the set functions below.

Using this as a reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```
function Login() {
  const [user, pass, setUser, setPass, test, setTest] = useState();

  return (
    <LoginWrapper>
      <Branding brand={brand.brandName} />
      <FormWrapper>
        <Stack>
          <TextInput
            type="text"
            label="Username"
            onChange={() => setUser(this)}
          />
        </Stack>
        <Stack>
          <TextInput
            type="password"
            label="Password"
            onChange={() => setPass(this)}
          />
        </Stack>
        <Stack padding="0" align="right">
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              setTest("user and pass");
            }}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </FormWrapper>
    </LoginWrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using `useState`, you will get an array where the first element is the initial state and the second element ist the setter for the state.

Your `pass` is actually the setter for `user`.

To use multiple values like you wanna do, you have to do something like this:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(...);
const [pass, setPass] = useState(...);
const [test, setTest] = useState(...);
```

Or as an alternative, you could use it as a combined object with a single `useState`, but than you have to merge it with the current state.

Comment: Or const [data, setData] = useState({user: null, pass: nulll, test: null})

Comment: Yes, that is the mentioned alternative at the end. But thanks for the code for that as well :+1:

Answer (score 0):

You might also get this error when writing elements for setting states and using curly braces "{" instead of brackets "["

× : const {user, setUser} = useState(...);

✓ : const [user, setUser]= useState(...);

Comment: Wrong answer. Asker used square brackets, not curly brackets

Comment: i was just adding another instance in which such error could occur